# Query Dataframe Column on String Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to grab values where the column startswith either value `'MA', 'KP'`.

I am trying to chain my dataframe query as such:

```
df.loc[df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("KP")==True | df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("MA")==True]
```

This doesn't seem to work because the column contains pd.nan objects (NULL values).

By themselves, the queries work, how can I merge these two queries together?

Thank you

Here is my error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  Debug Probe, prompt 40, line 1
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 892, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: So, the *column name* needs to start with either "MA" or "KP?" Then why are you trying to grab the values starting with "MA" or "KP"? Your question and attempt are at odds with each other.

Comment: is that expression being used in an if, for or some other conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question we see a lot.

```
df.loc[
    # 2. This returns a whole lot of `True`s or `False`s
    df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("KP")==True
    # 1. `|` is expecting a `True` or `False`
    | 
    # 2. This returns a whole lot of `True`s or `False`s
    df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("MA")==True
]
```

Fix it by wrapping conditions with parenthesis

```
df.loc[
    # 1. Series of `True`s or `False`s
    (df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("KP")==True)
    # 2. `|` is now a operator on `pd.Series` and is expecting `pd.Series`
    | 
    # 1. Series of `True`s or `False`s
    (df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("MA")==True)
]
```

---

That said, I'd do this

```
df.loc[df.REFERRAL_GRP.str.match('^KP|MA')]
```

Answer (score 2):

try numpy [logical_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[np.logical_or(df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("KP")==True , df['REFERRAL_GRP'].str.startswith("MA")==True)]
```